# Fortran Program Compiling: Segmentation Fault only on Windows

Tags: macos, windows-7, fortran, gfortran

i'm trying to compile Datcom [More Info Here](http://www.pdas.com/datcom.html), i succeeded in doing this on Mac OSX with gfortran. 
To do the same on W7 i downloaded MinGW and did the same things that i did on Mac but i get

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference 
Backtrace for this error:
#0 6f6a5456
#1 6f69321f
#2 004011e9
```

when i'm starting the program...

```
$ datcom.exe
Enter the input file name:
EX1.INP
```

Comment: Try compiling with the option `-fbounds-check` - if you are accessing an array incorrectly this will tell you at runtime which array and which index are causing the problem.

Comment: Ok. Using the program after the recompiling, i get a new error:
`At line 11 of NMTEST.F90`
`Fortran Runtime error: Index '2' of dimension 1 of array 'kol' above upper bound of 1`

In MacOSX anyway it works correctly :/

Comment: I believe this is because the code follows old convetion that arr(1) means arr(*) (assumed sized array).  so need to find how to treat 1 as * (or rewrite all of such by hand, which is impractical)

Comment: For some versions of gfortran there was a `-fugly-assumed` which should fix this but I am not sure recent versions support it. What version are you using on Mac and what version with mingw?

Comment: You could try playing with `-std=` option... maybe try `-std=legacy` first, or `-std=f95`

Comment: @robince 
Mac OSX => GCC 4.5.4
W7 => GCC 4.7.2

Comment: tried with `-std=legacy` and `-std=f95`. Always Segmentation Fault. :(

Comment: well the obvious suggestion then is to try 4.5.4 on windows...

Comment: How can i install different gcc version on MinGW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of your suggestions i succeeded in building datcom.
I succeeded installing Cygwin with gcc4 (that ships with 4.5.3 gfortran version). With this version simply doing

```
gfortran -o datcom *.F90
```

compiled correctly the software.

I don't know if it would have worked with Cygwin and new version of gfortran.

Thanks a lot